# rails model scope doesnt select good query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I would like to select my Offers bookable,
I compare arrival and departure dates search params with bookings confirmed dates of each offer in a scope.

Offer model:

```
has_many :bookings

scope :booking_available, -> (arrival_date, departure_date) {
  includes(:bookings)
    .references(:bookings)
    .where.not(
      'bookings.arrival_date <= ? AND
      bookings.departure_date >= ? AND
      bookings.status != ?',
      arrival_date,
      departure_date,
      0
    )
}
```

Booking model:

```
belongs_to :offer
```

And call it in my search function in controller.

```
if offer_params[:arrival_date].present? && offer_params[:departure_date].present?
  @offers = @offers.booking_available(
    offer_params[:arrival_date],
    offer_params[:departure_date]
  )
end
```

But the result give me only offers not available, I think `.not` in my query doesn't work and I don't know how fix it.

Comment: That `.not` makes no sense. If you remove it, you should get the correct results.

Comment: Without the `.not` i got the same result

Comment: Can you add the schema of both tables to your question @AntoineWako?

Comment: Could you better explain the sentence *"I would like to select my Offers available during dates range"*? When is an offer considered *available*?

Comment: It's tough to answer what's wrong with this query without seeing the model its in, and its relationship to bookings.  But a surface look suggests you should query for bookings within that date range, rather than not all the bookings outside of it.

Comment: I edited my question with better explanation, i would like select my offers bookable by compare given arrival/departure dates with bookings of each offer

Comment: Does `bookings.status = 0` mean that it is bookable? If not, what is the meaning of the status `0`?

Comment: It mean its "pending" booking so the dates of this booking still bookable

Comment: That `not` is going to invert everything in the WHERE clause, which is probably NOT what you want.

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement that is generated by this scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the complexity, I think you need to break this apart, so that you can test the pieces individually.

You describe the business logic as "offers who don't have bookings where... (conditions)".

This suggests a query like:

```rb
Offer.joins("left outer join bookings on bookings.offer_id = offers.id").
      select("offers.*, count(bookings.id)").
      group("offers.id").
      having("count(bookings.id) = 0")

# yeah, I didn't write it as a scope, b/c it's a bit more readable
# you can make it a scope if you wish
```

write a test and make sure this gives you the correct result. It does not yet select "bookings available". So now we add the bookings available criterion:

```rb
available_bookings = Booking.available(ar_date, dep_date).to_sql

joins = "left outer join (#{available_bookings}) as available_bookings on available_bookings.offer_id = offers.id"

Offer.joins(joins).
      select("offers.*, count(available_bookings.id)").
      group("offers.id").
      having("count(available_bookings.id) = 0")
```

By delegating the booking availability criteria to the Booking model, we can test it separately. Let me see if I have correctly understood what you mean by an available booking:

```rb
# booking.rb

scope :available, ->(arrival_date, departure_date){ 
       outside_of(arrival_date, departure_date).not_pending(arrival_date, departure_date) 
}

scope :outside_of, ->(arrival_date, departure_date){ 
       where("arrival_date <= ? and departure_date >= ?", arrival_date, departure_date) 
}

scope :not_pending, ->(arrival_date, departure_date){ 
       where.not("arrival_date >= ? and departure_date <= ? and status != ?",arrival_date, departure_date, 0)
}
```

This gives you three scopes on Booking that you can test separately.

Testing the components is critical here, to make sure each one works as intended.

Stylistically, too, it's good practice (maybe even best practice) to keep the scopes for bookings in the Booking model, and not to have them in the Offer model. Testability being one of the reasons.

Let us know how this works out.

Comment: I got error `column "booking_count" does not exist` when i test the first query

Comment: @AntoineWako I fixed the error. Give it a try now.

Comment: @AntoineWako I forgot to fix the error in the second query, but I don't think that's where you're seeing a problem, right? I'm testing this (similar, on one of my own apps) on Rails 6.1.3.2. What version are you using? Check carefully that booking_count is defined as the alias for count(bookings.id) in the select clause.

Comment: Yes its on the first query, I use Rails 5.2.1, i tried to move having before group because i readed the alias can be overwrite but it doesnt work

Comment: @AntoineWako in the rails console, please append `.to_sql` to the query that is not working, and show us the actual sql query that is being produced.

Comment: The result is `"SELECT offers.*, count(bookings.id) AS booking_count FROM \"offers\" left outer join bookings on bookings.offer_id = offers.id GROUP BY offers.id HAVING (booking_count = 0) ORDER BY \"offers\".\"updated_at\" DESC"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235891/discussion-between-les-nightingill-and-antoine-wako).

Comment: What is the best way and efficient method to add anoter table `ExternalBooking` in joins and compare available external bookings in same time ?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need to check if:

- given a **date interval** `P`
- list all sets `A` that do not intersect `P`

`A` intersects `P` if:

- `A.arrival_date   <= P.departure_date`, and
- `A.deperture_date >= P.arrival_date`

Hence, just swapping the order of the parameters should suffice:

```
has_many :bookings

scope :booking_available, -> (arrival_date, departure_date) {
  includes(:bookings)
    .references(:bookings)
    .where.not(
      'bookings.arrival_date <= ? AND
      bookings.departure_date >= ? AND
      bookings.status != ?',
      departure_date,
      arrival_date,
      0
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your scope condition</strike>

```rb
...
    .where.not(
      'bookings.arrival_date <= ? AND
      bookings.departure_date >= ? AND
      bookings.status != ?',
      arrival_date,
      departure_date,
      0
    )
...
```

will generate a WHERE query like this:

```
...
  WHERE NOT (bookings.arrival_date <= 'arrival_date'
    AND bookings.departure_date >= 'departure_date'
    AND bookings.status != 0)
```

which the same to

```
...
  WHERE NOT bookings.arrival_date <= 'arrival_date'
    OR NOT bookings.departure_date >= 'departure_date'
    OR NOT bookings.status != 0
```

Or simpler:

```
...
  WHERE bookings.arrival_date > 'arrival_date'
    OR bookings.departure_date < 'departure_date'
    OR bookings.status == 0
```

This, I guess, queries nearly all the data you have. Because this is logic operation, not filtering. You should remove `.not` and write it in positive:

```rb
...
    .where(
      'bookings.arrival_date > ? AND
      bookings.departure_date < ? AND
      bookings.status == ?',
      arrival_date,
      departure_date,
      0
    )
...
```

Does it express correct your business logic:~

Available bookings are bookings have:

- arrival date after `<arrival_date>` and
- departure date before `<departure_date>` and
- status is `0`

---

It's a bit complex but you could read the logic out of query below:

```rb
# query
arrival_date = "2021-07-10 01:00:00"
departure_date = "2021-07-20 01:00:00"

# query
select_query = "offers.*, " +
  "SUM(CASE WHEN arrival_date <= '#{arrival_date}' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS arrival_date_bound, " +
  "SUM(CASE WHEN departure_date >= '#{departure_date}' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS departure_date_bound, " +
  "COUNT(*) as total"
Offer.select(select_query)
  .left_outer_joins(:bookings)       # supported from rails 5+
  .where.not(bookings: {status: 0})
  .group("offers.id, offers.name")
  .having("arrival_bound + departure_bound = 0 AND total > 0")
```

This query joins offers with bookings, and group by offer. For each offer, we count numbers of pending bookings has `arrival_date` before a specific `arrival_date`, called `arrival_bound`. And count numbers of pending bookings has `departure_date` after a specific `departure_date`. And just get offers don't have these kind of bookings.
I add an extra total condition to filter out offers haven't booking.

I tried it with tests below. Only `o1` and `o5` have all bookings, which have both `arrival_date` and `departure_date` within range `t1`->`t4`

```rb
t0 = Time.new(2021,7, 5, 1, 0,0)
t1 = Time.new(2021,7,10, 1, 0,0) # arrival_date to query
t2 = Time.new(2021,7,13, 1, 0,0)
t3 = Time.new(2021,7,18, 1, 0,0)
t4 = Time.new(2021,7,20, 1, 0,0) # departure_date to query
t5 = Time.new(2021,7,25, 1, 0,0)

# offers have 1 booking
o1 = Offer.create!(name: "test 1")
Booking.create!(offer: o1, arrival_date: t2, departure_date: t3, status: 1)

o2 = Offer.create!(name: "test 2")
Booking.create!(offer: o2, arrival_date: t0, departure_date: t3, status: 1)

o3 = Offer.create!(name: "test 3")
Booking.create!(offer: o3, arrival_date: t2, departure_date: t5, status: 1)

o4 = Offer.create!(name: "test 4")
Booking.create!(offer: o4, arrival_date: t0, departure_date: t5, status: 1)

# offers have more than 1 booking
o5 = Offer.create!(name: "test 5")
Booking.create!(offer: o5, arrival_date: t2, departure_date: t3, status: 1)
Booking.create!(offer: o5, arrival_date: t2, departure_date: t3, status: 1)

o6 = Offer.create!(name: "test 6")
Booking.create!(offer: o6, arrival_date: t0, departure_date: t5, status: 1)
Booking.create!(offer: o6, arrival_date: t0, departure_date: t5, status: 1)

o7 = Offer.create!(name: "test 7")
Booking.create!(offer: o7, arrival_date: t2, departure_date: t3, status: 1)
Booking.create!(offer: o7, arrival_date: t2, departure_date: t5, status: 1)

o8 = Offer.create!(name: "test 8")
Booking.create!(offer: o8, arrival_date: t2, departure_date: t3, status: 1)
Booking.create!(offer: o8, arrival_date: t0, departure_date: t3, status: 1)
```

Comment: My buisness logic is available offers are offers who doesnt have bookings with date range outside of   `<arrival_date>.....<departure_date>` and last params is "ignore bookings who have date range inside but are pending state"